# How can I listen to a global shortcut key in React Native (Desktop app)?

Tags: macos, react-native, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible for a React Native desktop app on MacOs/Windows to listen to a global hotkey (e.g. ctrl+cmd+X)? By global I mean it can be pressed in any other app/window and still my app should capture the keypress.